# Android: Download File from Server & Start Download Activity

Tags: android, file, android-intent, download

Lets say I have a file in a Server, the file location on server is in:

C:\Training\MyTraining\100-01_24-Jul-2013_725764552.pdf

How do I download this PDF file? I want to download it the same way I download something from a public website on the internet, which goes like this:
1. I click on the link (Example: http://www.SomeWebsite.com/SomeFile.PDF)
2. The Android Download Activity Intent (Dialog) Starts asking me where do I want to save the file.
3. Click "OK" or "SAVE" to save the file.

Comment: This is very useful example :)

[Android Download File][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: do you actually have a server?